# How to use a ListView.builder to output a widget when a form is submitted

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hi I have a text form field and when the form is filled I want to output the values on multiple pages with the listview.builder currently I can output the data’s in a single container and when I’d fill the form again it doesn’t add another container it just updates the current container’s values
If anyone knows how to do it please help

Comment: what have you tried so far? explain with code snippets and screenshots so that someone here can easily understand the problem your trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete example:

**Source:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => new _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  List<String> _items = new List(); // to store comments

  final myController = TextEditingController();

  void _addComment() {
    if (myController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      // check if the comments text input is not empty
      setState(() {
        _items.add(myController.text); // add new commnet to the existing list
      });

      myController.clear(); // clear the text from the input
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("DEMO")),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Column(children: [
              Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      controller: myController,
                      maxLines: 5,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 15),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          _addComment();
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.send))
                  ]),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Text("${(index + 1)}. " + _items[index]));
                      }))
            ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and I’ve tried your answer but it’s not doing anything I input some data and tap the icon but it does nothing

Comment: Please share your code so that I can see if you are doing is correctly.

Comment: I’ll try to post but for now i can’t,the thing is I have a form on one page when the app opens it shows an empty page saying you have nothing and an add button which routes to the form page then after the form is filled it’s submitted back to the page with widget inheritance which displays a container with the form values from the form when I do this again it does not add another container instead it replace the old containers values with the new one can you help now

Comment: Share your code and I will modify it. You might have not implemented it in the correct way. I gave you an example of how to add multiple data and show it using a form. You can figure it to yourself where you have made a mistake.

Comment: My bad I didn’t call the controller in the body thank you so much @OMi Shah if it’s not too much can you adjust the code to route to another page and display the values and again thank you so much

Comment: please mark the solution as accepted and upvote too if it helped you.

And regarding that, please, edit your question and add your code. I will help then.

Comment: Sorry I was caught up with the code working I forgot to mark it and up vote it and my question is on the example you sent me can you edit it so that it can route to a new page with the values from the text field and build the list with the values retrieved